# Coding the same in LINQ when you have the SQL in good old SQL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

How would you start to code this in LINQ? I've got it working in SQL ok but still quite new to LINQ when I want to do something i've not tried before.

```
select * from waste 
where wasteid in (select x.wasteid
                from wasteindicatoritem x,wasteindicator r,hazardtype t  
                where x.wasteindicatorid = r.wasteindicatorid 
                and t.hazardtypeid = r.hazardtypeid 
                group by x.wasteid,t.Hazardous
                having count(*) >= 1 and t.hazardous = 0)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
var result= (
        from waste in db.waste
        where
            (
                from x in db.wasteindicatoritem
                join r in db.wasteindicator
                    on x.wasteindicatorid equals r.wasteindicatorid
                join r in db.hazardtype
                    on t.hazardtypeid equals r.hazardtypeid
                where
                    waste.wasteid==x.wasteid
                group new{x,t} by new{x.wasteid,t.Hazardous} into g
                select new
                {
                    nbrOf=g.Count(),
                    g.Key.Hazardous
                }
            ).Where(a=>a.nbrOf>=1 && Hazardous==0)
        select waste
    );
```

Where db is the linq data context